# Call a specific asp.net page through URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a specific .aspx page when i enter a URL in the browser.
Is it possible?Do i need to do some changes in the web.config file?

Comment: append it with the aspx file name.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: is there any other option other than appending the aspx file name?

Comment: Define your question a bit more clearly, it's not absolutely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you post your sample code ?

Comment: I need to provide a link or URL.When user enters this URL in the browser i should be redirected to a specific aspx page.

Comment: You can use URL Rewriting for it.

Comment: yes, Use URL rewriting by handling request in Global.asax file

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two pages page1.aspx and page2.aspx and you want that if anybody write page1.aspx and should be redirected to page2.aspx. Simply you have to call redirected to page2.aspx on page1.aspx.

Write the following code on page1.aspx

```
response.redirect("http://www.page2.aspx");
```